# matlab - arrayfun(..) call, "Not enough input arguments."

Tags: matlab

In the following boiled down example illustrating the error, the function `f_what(..)` should return the values of input argument `y` at indices in the array `ts`:

```
function Y = f_what(y, ts)

    function get_out = get(t)
        get_out = y(t);
    end

    Y = arrayfun(get, ts);

end
```

Calling it:

```
>> f_what(1:10, 1:5)
Error using f_what/get (line 4)
Not enough input arguments.

Error in f_what (line 7)
    Y = arrayfun(get, ts);
```

Also, for some reason, the following, where `get(..)` should be the same as the one above, works:

```
function Y = f_what(y, ts)

    get = @(t) y(t);

    Y = arrayfun(get, ts);

end
```

Calling it:

```
>> f_what(1:10, 1:5)

ans =

     1     2     3     4     5
```

"Not enough input arguments" ... `arrayfun(..)` should call its first argument with, in this case, one argument. And `get(..)` has one input argument. I don't get why it's not enough.

**Edit:** even more boiled down:

```
function Y = f_what

    function get_out = get_(t)
        get_out = t;
    end

    Y = arrayfun(get_, 1:5);

end
```

Still the same error.

**Edit 2:** It works if I supply `@get` to the first argument of `arrayfun(..)`, instead of `get`. But I still don't get why it doesn't work without the `@`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [arrayfun](http://www.google.no/search?q=arrayfun&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&hl=en-gb&client=safari) documentation

> func
>
> Handle to a function that accepts n input arguments and returns m output arguments.

A handle in matlab is denoted using @, so you need to pass @get as first parameter. Otherwise matlab tries to evaluate function get instead of obtaining its handle, which results in "not enough parameters" error.

In the example that works you defined get to be a handle to an anonymous function, that's why it worked.

Comment: So what exactly happens when Matlab "tries to evaluate function get"? Shouldn't it say "function handle expected as first argument" or something like that, rather than "Not enough input arguments" with reference to `get`?

Comment: @EvgeniSergeev It is not function arrayfun that displays the error. It is function get. Try to stop the code in the debugger at line 7 and run get, you will get the same. The code does not even manage to run arrayfun, you get the error on the stage of establishing parameters to arrayfun. You can not run get without parameters - that is what is giving you error.

Comment: Ah, I see! Of course, if the error was inside `arrayfun(..)`, then it would have appeared in the stack. Hmmm, I forgot Matlab had breakpoints...